# merging values horizontally in dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to merge two subsets of a dataframe together, but neither merge nor cbind seem to do exactly what I want. So far I have this:

```
library(psych)
df1<-NULL
df1$a<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
df1$b<-c(4,5,2,6,1)
df1$c<-c(0,9,0,6,3)
df1$gender<-c(0,0,0,1,1)
df1<-as.data.frame(df1)

male<-subset(df1,gender<1)
male<-male[,-c(4)]
female<-subset(df1,gender>=1)
female<-female[,-c(4)]

library(psych)
merge(corr.test(male)$r,corr.test(female)$r)
```

My end goal is something like this in every cell:

```
     a      b                 c
a    1/1    -0.6546537/-1    0/-1
....
```

Comment: it is not clear to me the desired output. The numbers of that matrix (or data frame) are: result of `corr.test` for male *divided by* result of `corr.test` for female?

Comment: Sorry, the `/` is meant to simply be a separator between the two values NOT a division symbol

Comment: @Rilcon42 So you're not actually trying to merge the values...It's just a way of expressing them. By the way, if you really want to "paste" a / b you would be working with characters and not numbers, is it ok? Also, in the cor.test what are you exactly trying to correlate? cor.test needs x and y arguments

Comment: I should have mentioned the fact that i am using the `psych` package (corr.test, as opposed to the standard cor.test)

Comment: Have you considered representing the data as an array? The 1st two dimensions are the rows and columns as you have them currently; the 3rd dimension could be of size 2, distinguishing between the two gender categories you have. This isn't useful for a visual representation, but depending on your intended use, it might be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate the entries in both matrices, then just fix the dimensions of the new vector to be the same as the `corr.test` output using `dim<-`, aka `dim(...) <-`.

```
## Concatenate the entries
strs <- sprintf("%s/%s", round(corr.test(male)$r,2),
                round(corr.test(female)$r, 2))

## Set the dimensions
dim(strs) <- c(3,3)

## Or (to have the value returned at the same time)
`dim<-`(strs, c(3, 3))
#      [,1]       [,2]       [,3]    
# [1,] "1/1"      "-0.65/-1" "0/-1"  
# [2,] "-0.65/-1" "1/1"      "0.76/1"
# [3,] "0/-1"     "0.76/1"   "1/1"
```

Another trick, if you want to have those rownames and column names as in the output of `corr.test`, and not have to worry about dimensions,

```
## Get one result
ctest <- corr.test(male)$r

## Concatenate
strs <- sprintf("%s/%s", round(ctest,2),
                round(corr.test(female)$r, 2))

## Overwrite the matrix with the strings
ctest[] <- strs

ctest
#   a          b          c       
# a "1/1"      "-0.65/-1" "0/-1"  
# b "-0.65/-1" "1/1"      "0.76/1"
# c "0/-1"     "0.76/1"   "1/1"
```